# Objective-C - generating source code reports

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing

I am facing a following problem:  I need to generate detailed reports for Objective-C  source code (written for iOS). I need to be able to display following:

**Class report:**
Class name | File location | Number of methods
ClassA | /my/path/ClassA.m | 7
ClassB | /my/path/ClassB.m | 12
....

**Methods report:**
Method name | Class name | File location
method1 | ClassA | /my/path/ClassA.m
method2 | ClassA | /my/path/ClassA.m
....

And I also need to be able display few other reports but at this moment I am interested just to start from somewhere.

*Please note:*
- At the moment I do not have requirement to have number of lines/complexity/etc displayed.
- Report similar to above one is sufficient (as long as it contains information above I will be really happy; I can parse the info and create the report that is needed)
- I have already looked at Doxygen and its xml output but for few sample projects that I run I did not get all methods listed in xml documentation (even though they are in the files).  I have to investigate why these methods are not showing up.

Thanks in advance to all the answers/hints/comments....

Comment: @Teofilo Israel Vizcaino Rodrig: As the code uses numerous classes some of which are third party most of the code is not documented.  That being I said I automatically uses "EXTRACT_ALL = YES" in Doxygen.  But your comment got me thinking and I checked the rest of settings in Doxygen I noticed that (EXTRACT_ALL) does not 'extract all' so I went back set other options to YES (e.g. private members will not). I just run it and output looks much better.  Thanks for the comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your proficiency with Java, you might want to take a look at [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/). It also has a grammar for parsing Objective-C 2.0.

http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2010/Sep/msg00097.html

I confess I barely opened the grammar to look at how complex/simple it is. It looked well organized but I didn't experiment with it myself. Generally speaking, JavaCC looks a bit steep at first glance but with a couple of hours of toying around with it, you should find your marks pretty quickly. Once you get it though, parsing any language becomes really easy.

Comment: I will check out for sure to see what I can get from JavaCC.

Answer (score 1):

Our [Source Code Search Engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine) would probably help you do this nicely.

SCSE is normally used interactively to search across large source codes and inspect the code.  It understands the elements of the langusges it is searching, and it has an option for Objective C.   Because it understands language syntax, it isn't confused by whitespace or comments or strings with funny content.  It can also record the results of searches as text logs and/or XML files of hits and locations (file, line).

One can use it in batch scripts to do searches and capture results.

To do what you want, you'd give the SCSE the following queries and log the results into XML (forgive my ObjectiveC syntax, I'm not a programmer in such):

```
    '@implementation' I     -- this would find class declarations, bind I and capture line #
    '@interface' I  -- if you wanted these, too
    '@end'   -- would find end-of-class declarations
    '+' '(' I ')' '{'  -- find method declations and bind name
    '-' '(' I ')' '{'  -- find static method declarations
```

Now you have a set of XML files that describe where these elements are.   Integrating the hits gives you an outline model of classes and content, and computing your values from this information should be pretty straightforward.

If you want a more precise answer, our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) has a [full Objective C parser](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/ObjectiveCFrontEnd.html).  This information is easily extracted from the AST that the parser produces.

Comment: Hi Ira,  to be frank I did not think at all in that direction (doing searches on the files). I will definitely have to check out your Source Code Search Engine to see if can solve my problems. Thanks alot for the suggestion.